# Is it possible to run cpulimit on a snap app?

Tags: ubuntu

Applications installed with snappy (snapd) are just symlinks to `/usr/bin/snap` binary. Eg. `/snap/bin/chromium -> /usr/bin/snap*`

So I guess I can't just use: `cpulimit -l 80 /snap/bin/vscode`

When I tried it returned `Process 29977 dead!`, which I guess means snapd forked  process and as result **cpulimiting** is not in use.

Is it possible to cpulimit snap apps?

Not sure about all of this, just my guessings. Looking for a proper explanation.